# I can't access to share using URI

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

I have a Windows 2008 Server R2 64 which is member of AD and configured as DFS.

My clients (Windows 7) can access the DFS with IP and ComputerName (\\192.168.0.6, \\dfs).
But using \\dfs.mycompany.com prompt this error:

Windows cannot access \\dfs.mycompany.com
You do not have permission to access \\dfs.mycompany.com. Contact your network administrator to request access.

Is there anything that I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a name other than the computer name to try and access the share?
If you are then [this](http://datacomguy.blogspot.com/2009/10/disable-strict-name-checking.html) may be the issue.

Basically you need to [disable strict name checking](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308).  Although this is normally only an issue on Server 2000 and Server 2003, it can be an issue on a newer server if it decides to use SMB version 1 for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a different name which defined as CNAME in DNS Server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean that you're trying to access the DFS root, in which case it's accessed as:

```
\\DomainName\DfsRootName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try accessing it from **\\mycompany.com\dfs**; not **\\dfs.mycompany.com**.

Comment: I did it before with other file server, I just want to add new one!